# Fire onclick without position absolute or fixed

Tags: css, events, onclick, position, absolute

Is there a way to fire the onclick event in a div tag without css: position absolute?

```
<div onclick="fireevent();">
 SOME TEXT or IMG
</div>


function fireevent(){
alert("fired");
}
```

This does only work if I add some css with position:absolute. Any other way? Because I can't put the div to a special position.

Comment: In general, events are NOT influenced by CSS. Would you prefer a pure JS solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery http://jsfiddle.net/gbce1u55/

```
$('div').click(function(){
alert("fired");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the div to a minimum height and width so that an event is triggered on clicking within the set size.
A better suggestion is to fire events on clicking specific tag elements (like text or images) rather than clicking the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem:

I changed the innerHTML by the event: mouseover / mouseout. This killed my click event.

Now I add an createElement(div) over my master-div with the changing text and the underlaying master-div fires the onclick.